# Calculate unique records in sql join

Tags: sql

Below query gives 400 record out of which 20 records is same based on UPC. In other words I want 20 distinct records based on UPC. How can I do it?

```
 select tc.ChainID,tc.UPC,tc.SupplierInvoiceNumber,pc.DateTimeCreated
     from #tmpCompareData tc
     left join ProductCatalog pc
    ON tc.ProductID=pc.ProductID
```

Comment: did you try `GROUP BY` ?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Well, depending on what you are after, one solution would be to group by `tc.UPC`.

For example:

```
SELECT
    MIN(tc.ChainID),
    tc.UPC,
    MIN(tc.SupplierInvoiceNumber),
    MIN(pc.DateTimeCreated)
FROM #tmpCompareData tc
    LEFT JOIN ProductCatalog pc
ON tc.ProductID = pc.ProductID
GROUP BY tc.UPC
```

Note, that you need to apply aggregate functions (`MIN()`, `MAX()`, etc.) to the other selected columns to tell SQL how you want to return that data.